# Video editing with text to speech

Tags: video-editor

I am trying to do some screen recordings and uploading them to YouTube. I have a terrible voice and frankly I cannot maintain a stream of speech meaning the the end product will end up being bad. I saw some videos online:

The uploader made use of text-to-speech (TTS) voices. Even though the voice is obviously terrible, the audio was perfectly synchronized with the video.

I am not asking for any sophisticated way of editing videos. All I want to know is a way I can easily add audio to my screen recordings. I have an old version of Camtasia and it doesn't provide a TTS engine meaning that I have to use another program, type what I want to be converted to speech, save as an audio file and import to Camtasia. The problem is that my videos are about 15 min long meaning that it will be an extremely tedious task to be using the two software simultaneously. In fact, what I'm most worried about is having to change some word and maintaining a good synchronicity between the video and audio.

So, I hope anyone with experience in creating such videos can direct me to the easiest way of doing it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, but why bother.  It is far faster and easier to record your dialog in multiple takes.  As long as you can naturally speak a sentence or two at a time, you can narrate your own video by carefully editing your dialog from multiple takes.  DAW tools will even play the video for you while you are dubbing over it and let you hear what happened before and after your take in order to give you context.  This is faster and will sound better than your text to speech solution.

If you still really want to do text to speech, I would recommend taking the same kind of approach.  Make clips for each of the phrases you need and then move them in to the video and place them as needed.

Comment: That takes a long time and that is why I'm posing the question in the first place. Do you know of any video editor with a TTS engine ?

Comment: It's still going to take longer to get the timing correct on synthesized speech than on natural speech, even if you have an integrated TTS engine unless you need a whole lot of takes of each sentence to get something you are comfortable with.  I don't know of any software that has TTS built in because there is no good reason from a production stand point to do it.  It adds absolutely zero value to the software.

Comment: The problem is I can't even stand my own voice. Did you check the video I referenced in my original post. Its perfectly synchronized.

Comment: @user47181 - then you can do the other thing I suggested of TTSing the lines and placing them.  That's how you get highly accurate sync of dialog is placing it by hand.

Comment: Use a voice filter or pitch down/up your voice and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Like AJ, I don't know of any built-in text-to-speech video editors, though MacOS supports speech reading of text in any app that uses standard text controls. (For example TextEdit.app.) I assume Windows has something similar.

If that's too much work, you could always "hire talent" (i.e. get a friend to do it) if you don't like your own voice.

bakkelun's suggestion of using audio filters on your own voice is not at all unusual. There are many people on YouTube who have done this.